# Polyhedral cone representation as conical combination

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following.

Suppose $P\subset R^n$ is a polyhedral cone ($P=\{x\in R^n:Ax\leq0\}$). Sow that $P=cone\{ x_1,...,x_k\}$, for some $x_i\in R^n$, $i=1,...,k$.

My question is as follows.

The polyhedral cone is just the intersection of a finite number of halfspaces that cross the origin. So, to represent $P$, wouldn't it be sufficient to just choose two of the most extreme halfspaces (say the $i$th and $j$th halfspace), pick two vectors on the boundary of each halfspace (one vector orthogonal to $a_i^T$ and the other orthogonal to $a_j^T$th (with the right directions)) and, then, construct the polyhedral cone using the conical combination of these two vectors? Why is it required to choose $k$ such vectors to construct the cone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose two vectors on  the most extreme halfspaces then you may generate a cone in the usual *geometric* sense ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone)), i.e. an n-dimensional  convex body where intersections with planes are (n-1)-dimensional balls.

A *polyhedral* cone, however, is defined as a convex subset of a vector space  under linear combinations with positive coefficients ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone)). As  the name says, it is used in the representation theory of polyhedra. You may construct them from *as many* boundary vectors or halfplanes.

Here is a simple  example in $n$ dimensions which shows that indeed $n$ conditions are needed:  Let $e_i$ be the unit vector in dimension $i$, and let the cone be all positions $x$ with $x = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i e_i$ with $c_i \geq 0$. So your cone is the first orthant. Expressing the same in halfspaces, you have  written (in your question) the conditions as $A x \leq 0$ and the matrix $A$ is

$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\0 & -1 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0& \dots & -1 \end{bmatrix}\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: In the question though the polyhedral cone is defined as $\{x\in R^n: Ax\leq 0\}$ with the standard ordering!

Comment: ok then k boundary vectors or k halfplanes. You can't get less.

Comment: Okay. Here's why I'm confused. The feasible set of the polyhedral cone as defined in my problem statement lies between the two extreme halfspaces. If you think in 2-dim, it's an unbounded triangle. Every point in this triangle can be expressed as a conical comb. of the two vectors orthogonal to $a_i^T$ and $a_j^T$. So, I don't see why we need another $k-2$ vectors to get the feasible set.

Comment: In two dimensions you are right. In the main text I put  a simple  example in n dimensions which shows that you indeed need n conditions in any case.